# Placing a label above a feature in 3D/Scene using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, 3d, local-scene

Is it possible (using ArcGIS Pro, 2.5.1) to manually or by derived extrusion (i.e. from a DTM) set the height of a label to sit/float above a feature? I see you can use an extrusion but that requires the label vector having a z value?

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363925/placing-a-label-above-a-feature-in-3d-scene-using-arcgis-pro#comment595505_363925):

> Due to the ongoing bug related to Scene labelling the best way round
> I've currently found for this is to do the below. Create a new point
> file using Extract Values to Points (input raster and append
> attributes from original point file). Then display the new point file,
> with symbols as no colour and elevation based on the new field plus a
> vertical exaggeration. Then labels sit at this new elevation.

.